# Trying to prevent a custom checkbox from jumping when checked

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I was making some custom radio and checkboxes for a project scheduled for next week and I thought maybe something a little different like an "X" instead of a check. To make this question short and simple:

Question:

- When this custom checkbox is checked, the check box jumps about 2px up. How do I prevent that behavior?

Possible Duplicate:

- Question: [Why do these checkbox-hacked radio buttons jump when they are selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424228/why-do-these-checkbox-hacked-radio-buttons-jump-when-they-are-selected)
- Differences: OP's CSS is a convoluted mess of `body` `nth-of-type` selectors and the only answer is unaccepted with a convoluted mess of CSS without an explanation of how it works.

Thank you for your time.

http://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/dGVPBd?editors=110

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 none hlsa(0%, 0, 0, 0);
  outline: 0 none hlsa(0%, 0, 0, 0);
}

html,
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  font: 400 2ch/1.1 'Verdana';
  color: #DDD;
  background: #111;
}

fieldset {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 19em;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 3px double #FF8;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

legend {
  font: small-caps 700 1.2rem/2 "Palatino Linotype";
  color: #FD1;
}

input {
  font: inherit;
}


/* CheX */

#chex input.chkrad {
  display: none;
}

#chex input.chkrad+label {
  color: #DDD;
}

#chex input.chkrad+label span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: -1px 4px 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#chex input+label span {
  line-height: 100%;
  background: #555;
}

input.X:checked+label span {
  padding: -3px 0 3px;
}

input.X:checked+label span:before {
  content: 'X';
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: oblique;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: #F00;
}


/* RadZ */

#radz input.chkrad {
  display: none;
}

#radz input.chkrad+label {
  color: #FC2;
}

#radz input.chkrad+label span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: -1px 15px 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#radz input+label span {
  line-height: 100%;
  background: #555;
}

input.A:checked+label span {
  padding: -5px 15px 5px;
}

input.A:checked+label span:before {
  content: '';
  color: #e3e;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: cursive;
}

input.B:checked+label span {
  padding: -5px 15px 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input.B:checked+label span:before {
  content: '';
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: cursive;
  text-align: left;
  color: #f99;
}

input.C:checked+label span {
  padding: -2px 15px 2px;
}

input.C:checked+label span:before {
  content: '';
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: #3ef;
  line-height: .75;
}

input.fade+label span,
input.fade:checked+label span {
  transition: background 0.7s linear;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="chex" name="chex">
  <legend>Checkbox X</legend>
  <input id="chk3" name='chk3' class="chkrad X fade" type='checkbox' value='x' />
  <label for="chk3"><span></span>Red "X" mark</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="radz" name="radz">
  <legend>Radio Group</legend>
  <input id="rad1" name='rad' class="chkrad A fade" type='radio' value='1' />
  <label for="rad1"><span></span>Brawl</label>
  <br/>
  <input id="rad2" name='rad' class="chkrad B fade" type='radio' value='2' />
  <label for="rad2"><span></span>Women</label>
  <br/>
  <input id="rad3" name='rad' class="chkrad C fade" type='radio' value='3' />
  <label for="rad3"><span></span>Drink</label>
  <br/>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the

```
line-height: 100%;
```

for the span http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgWjJd?editors=110

fixed it for me.

Comment: Indeed it did, sir.:-) I'll accept your answer in approx. 6 min.

Answer (score 1):

Frank's answer is probably cleaner, but here's an alternative...

```
input.X:checked + label span:before {
...
position:relative;
float:left;
```

}

From there adjust padding or font size to center the'X'

```
padding-left: -5px;
padding-top: -7px;
font-size: 8px;
```